# How to mock array data with object for unit testing in Angular 8

Tags: arrays, angular, unit-testing

I would like to write a unit test to test if the `expectedData` is showing as expected. The HTML code is working and it displays everything correctly.

HTML code:

```html
<div class="col-6 p-0 LHS" *ngIf="data && data.type === 'App'">
  <div *ngFor="let d of data">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-auto">Item1:</div>
      <div class="appItem1">{{d.item1}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

TS file:

```
  data = [{item1: "Item 1", item2: "Item 2"}, type: "App", display: true]; // sample input data
  expectedData;

  getExpectedData() {
    if (this.data && this.data.item) {
      switch (this.data.type) {
        case ("File"):
           this.expectedData = $('.fileItem1')[0].innerHTML;  
          break;
        case ("App"):
          this.expectedData = $('.appItem1')[0].innerHTML;              
          break;
      }
    }
  }
```

My test case:

```
it('should verify expected data', () => {
    const mockdata= [{item1: "Item 1"}];
    mockdata.type= 'App'; // getting error because this can't be pushed to array
    mockdata.display= true; // getting error because this can't be pushed to array
    component.data = mockdata;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.getExpectedData();
    expect(component.expectedData).toBe("Item 1");
  });
```

However, in my test case, it doesn't seem to be working to mock the data to that type of data, are there any possible way to test the `getExpectedData()`?

Thanks

Comment: So what is the problem? You dont know how to push object into an array ?

Comment: I data actually an array or an object?

Comment: @Antoniossss The problem is I'm not able to mock that data to test that method. It's an array but with the json data which is confusing, so I couldn't create the test data.

Comment: your code shows its not an array but an object. See this `this.data.type`?? This is how you access object's properties, not array elements.

Comment: Mocking is not a problem as it will work just as you try to do it. The problem here is broken data model.

Comment: it looks strange to me too, but that is the array. do you have any ideas to assign the `component.data` to something else in order to test  `getExpectedData()`?

Comment: Its not a valid array content. That will not even compile. It does not "look strange" - its just invalid.

Comment: I've added the screenshot of the real data from the ts file. please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why you have a mutated array, but so be it. The one of the answers is to use

`//@ts-ignore`

```
const mockdata= [{item1: "Item 1"}];
//@ts-ignore
mockdata.type= 'App'; 
//@ts-ignore
mockdata.display= true; 
component.data = mockdata;
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ae5pvs?file=index.ts

[image]